# get C2DM auth token without passing your password?

Tags: android, python, oauth, android-c2dm, google-authentication

I'm working on a C2DM app using appengine on Python. After several hours of wondering why my "send message" was giving me an error 401 I discovered that my auth token was wrong. I've looked at several examples and noticed that most people retrieve the token by passing the email address and password as request parameters example:

```
username = self.request.get('username') 
        password = self.request.get('password') 
        values = {'accountType' : 'HOSTED', 
                  'Email' : username, 
                  'Passwd' : password, 
                  'source' : 'shiprack-brain-1', 
                  'service' : 'ac2dm'} 
        data = urllib.urlencode(values) 
        request = urllib2.Request('https://www.google.com/accounts/ 
ClientLogin', data) 
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Is there a way to get the Auth Token needed for C2DM messaging without passing your gmail password?

Answer (score 1):

No.

It's recommended to use a separate account for C2DM instead of using the account used for email and other services.